# laravel (vuejs and vuex) Too many arguments to function in callResetPassword

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm creating forgot password on my web application using laravel (with vue and vuex). I found a good tutorial (https://codebriefly.com/vue-js-reset-password-laravel-api/) but sadly it cant reset the password because of error

> **message:** *Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controller\API\AuthController::callResetPassword(), 0 passed
>   and exactly 2 expected*

I don't know how to fix it.

---

### Codes

*web.php*

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function (){
    return view('layout');
})->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.-]*');
```

*routes.js*

```
{
    path: '/reset-password',
    name: 'reset-password',
    component: ForgotPassword,
    meta: { middlewareGuest: true }

},
{
    path: '/reset-password/:token',
    name: 'reset-password-form',
    component: ResetPasswordForm,
    meta: { middlewareGuest: true }

},
```

*AuthController.php* (handle the reseting password)

```
  public function callResetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->save();
        event(new PasswordReset($user));
    }
```

*auth.js* (Vuex)

```
resetPassword(data){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        axios.post('/reset/password',{
            token: data.token,
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password
        })
        .then(response =>{
            resolve(response)
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            reject(error)
        })
    })
}
```

ResetPasswordForm.vue

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(["resetPassword"]),
    reset() {
       this.resetPassword({
        token: this.$route.params.token, 
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      })
        .then(response => {
          toast.fire({
            type: "success",
            title: "Password reset successfully."
          });
          this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          swal.fire({
            type: "error",
            text: error.response.data.message,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000
          });
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can already tell this has nothing to do with your Vue application. Somewhere in you API `callResetPassword` is called without any arguments. Go take a look in that file and try to track down where this method is called. If you cannot find it, replace the vue code from your answer with some code of your API.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen so the problem is the controller ?

Comment: I glanced at the tutorial you provided. Axios post request is made to this function with parameters email, password, and reset token. So make sure that you are actually sending them to your controller.

Comment: @DinoNumić How can correct the error?

Comment: @Peejong I assume you implemented axios part since you are getting the error. You'll have to debug it to figure out why it's not sending the parameters properly. You can hardcode your email and password to check whether that will help. If that works than you know that Vue is not getting values from the inputs. Update question with your axios implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your javascript call or your api call in genereal, so somewhere in your script you are calling this method `callResetPassword` without passing any parameters.

In this case you need to call the method `callResetPassword($user, $password)` with your `$user` and `$password`

You should have something like this:

```
    requestResetPassword() {
        this.$http.post("/auth/reset/password/", {
            token: this.$route.params.token,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
            password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation
        .then(result => {
            this.response = result.data;
            console.log(result.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Comment: I create a vuex action just like that and i import in on the vue file but the error still there.

Comment: @Peejong can you check if the data actually holds values in your axios call, just console.log them

Comment: @Peejong no problem sir, just console.log these for instance `token: data.token,email: data.email,password: data.password` and check if they actually contain value. I can help you tomorrow again (in 10 hours, if you like to :))

Comment: how can i type it and where can i  put it?